# When to use Android LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata

My android app has a cart activity where I use LiveData with a CartRepository and Room database to display the items in the cart. It works great. In the toolbar I have an actionLayout (below) with a cart icon with a textview that shows the number of items in the cart. I'm curious if this is a place where I should also use LiveData? Is there a way to turn this into some kind of component that utilizes LiveData to update whenever the items in the cart change? If so, how would I do this?
Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_cart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the list of cart items in your `CartActivity` based on `LiveData`? If so, you can simply use this to update the `TextView` when `onChanged()` is called

Answer (score 0):

You will need to observe changes from your Cart repository in your activity. To do that you can use view model in between your repository and activity. So instead of directly using LiveData from your repository, have it pass through view model. After doing so, observe changes in data (in your case it's number of items in the cart) in your activity and update textview once you get the newer number (or any data).

One advantage of using view model is - even if your lifecycle owner (activity or fragment) gets destroyed and recreated , same instance of view model connects to newer lifecycle owner. This way you never lose your current state in the app.